# Oracle 11g installation (failed due to using _ in the hostname)

Tags: oracle, installation

I'm trying to install Oracle DB 11.2, I've got below error, which is violation of using under score in the host name. I've changed both /etc/hosts and /home/oracle/.bash_profile as below but it seems it set in another location, because every time it shows the same error while I've changed my hostname.

[image]

[image]

After saw this error, I checked my `tnsnames.ora` and `listener.ora`, and the hostname was set to bi_etl_rtl.ttcom.local wrongly. then I set them manually in these two files. but nothing fixed.

Also, I removed the database using dbca and removed the /u01/app/oracle path manually, and then start to installation, again it shows that you cannot use underscore in your hostname, while I changed the hostname everywhere I know.
This oracle installer where will find this wrong hostname, what should I do?

Comment: Also i need to mention that i'm receiving below error, when want to startup DB in SQLPLUS .                                                                                                         
  ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/dbs/initDB11G.ora'

Comment: What does `hostname` or `uname -n` report? And which operating system are you running? You can't just change it in `/etc/hosts` but what else you have to do depends on the OS. This is off-topic for this site, but is probably a duplicate on another site in the network.

Comment: I'm using oracle linux 7

Comment: [Rename RedHat7 hostname without reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/313046/33295).

Comment: Could you please describe your purpose in detail?